# Django rest framework : How to accept only json data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like my Django rest framework API's to accept only Json data. So i set it in the default settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
}
```

but the views are still accepting the multipart form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded.

If i set the MultiPartParser in view than only multi form data is accepted , If i set the JSONParser in view than both multi form data and json is accepted.

How can i make it to accept only json data by default and multi-part only for a view in which i am uploading a file?

Comment: See [Setting the parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#setting-the-parsers) for setting different parsers for different views.

Comment: I'm using your exact settings and it works, could be possible that you have some sort of plugin that sets the `parser_classes` for your views?

Answer (score 8):

If I'm comprehending it correct, you need to specify `REST_FRAMEWORK` variable in settings like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],

}
```

Comment: Hi my settings are in the same format. Using [ instead of ( doesn't have any effect. Editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: You can also accept different parsers for every view with `parser_classes = (JSONParser, )`.